# Update item views from Backbone collection add

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, inversion-of-control, underscore.js

I have a `ListView` and `ItemView` for a list. `ListCollection` is used as the **collection** for `ListView`. Now if I get additional new collection (e.g. more items in the list) and `add()` into `ListCollection`, how should I go about **rendering the list** in general after `add` event?

1. Should I do `collection.add(newCollection)`? And then loop through `newCollection` to add model by model while heave `ItemView` to bind into model's `add` event to render?
2. Or should I loop through each model in `newCollection` to create new model, then add into `ListCollection`? Each loop with call `ItemView.render()`

What I don't want to do is to re-render the whole ListView which is too inefficient.

Let me know if there is a good option between those two or a third one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out using **LayoutManager** and put this event binding to call `addOne` from `initialize`

```
this.collection.on("add", this.addOne, this);
```

The `addOne` function will basically use `insertView` from **LayoutManager**

```
this.insertView(new ItemView({model: model})).render();
```

It's simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to have your process of adding an item view for a model separate from looping over the collection. Then you can call the same function from your initial render, when looping, and from the on "add" event.

```
ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // ...
});

ListView = Backbone.View.Extend({

  initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on("add", this.addItemView, this);
  },

  addItemView: function(item){
    var view = new ItemView({
      model: item
    });
    view.render();

    this.$el.append(view.$el);
  },

  render: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.addItemView);
  }

});
```

FWIW, MarionetteJS handles all of this for you:

```
ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#some-template"
});

CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  itemView: ItemView
});

var cv = new CollectionView({
  collection: someCollection
});

cv.render();
```

You can find more info about Marionette at http://marionettejs.com

Comment: what is the purpose of  `_.bind(this.addItemView, this);` if `this` is being passed as the context in the following `.on()` statement ?

Comment: oops. :P the _.bind is not needed. wasn't thinking when i typed that.

Comment: I couldn't make sense of the above calling `this.addItemView` within `render`. Maybe I miss something? But I use Backbone LayoutManager so is there a best practice for it?